# Update Database with Textboxes

Tags: c#, database, textbox

I'm trying to get these textboxes to show data from a database, i'm able to show the data but everytime I try to update it won't save. Here's what i've done

```
    private void ClubRecord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sConnection = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source = Eastern_Property_Maintenance.mdb";

            dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
            dbConn.Open();

            sql = "SELECT * FROM Club ORDER BY CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CompanyPhone;";
            dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
            dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
            dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

            dbreader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dbreader.Read())
            {
                string CompanyName = dbreader["CompanyName"].ToString();
                string CompanyAddress = dbreader["CompanyAddress"].ToString();
                string CompanyPhone = dbreader["CompanyPhone"].ToString();

                txtCompanyName.Text = CompanyName;
                txtCompanyAddress.Text = CompanyAddress;
                txtCompanyPhone.Text = CompanyPhone;
            }

            dbreader.Close();
           // dbConn.Close();
        }

        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void btnConfirmChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string companyName = txtCompanyName.Text;
        string companyAddress = txtCompanyAddress.Text;
        string companyPhone = txtCompanyPhone.Text;

        string Update = "UPDATE [Club] SET [CompanyName]= @CompanyName,[CompanyAddress]=@CompanyAddress,[CompanyPhone]=@CompanyPhone";
        OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand(Update, dbConn);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", companyName);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyAddress", companyAddress);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyPhone", companyPhone);

        try
        {
            dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Update Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            return;
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: FYI with no *where* clause your update would overwrite every row in the table, is that what you want?

Comment: "It won't save" - does that mean the code executes, but the database doesn't receive the connection?

Comment: What are you having problems with? Displaying the data or updating it? This is not clear from your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Remove the try and catch or debug and tell us where the code stops.

Comment: i'm having problems updating it

Comment: @user3703020: *What* problems?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does it fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Is there an error?  What is that error?  Does your code even *reach* the point where you execute the update query?  You have to put in at least *some* effort.

Comment: Hi! Have you any message from message box?

Comment: i run debugger, the textboxes show the data, i try to change companyphone, the message box pops up saying "update complete" i exit out of this form to my main menu, i return to the form and the data hasn't changed no errors. hope that explains a bit better

Comment: Look in the table. You are loading *all* the rows from the table, putting them in the text boxes but then immediately replacing them in the loop with the values from the next row.

Comment: Thanks alot for all your help guys and sorry i wasn't clear on my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subtle typo error, but I think that there is something to learn here, so I want to give a full answer:

You create a command called `dbcmd`

```
OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand(Update, dbConn);
```

but then you fill the parameter collection of a different command `dbCmd` and executes this one.

```
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", companyName);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyAddress", companyAddress);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyPhone", companyPhone);
```

C# is case sensitive, so the twos are not the same command, but how does it lead to the failed update is worth to look at.
You have declared a global OleDbCommand variable named `dbCmd` and this variable is still set to the SELECT query used to load the textboxes. So, when you call `ExecuteNonQuery` it does not update anything.

You could fix the problem simply changing all the references in the updated code from `dbCmd` to `dbcmd`. But, the lesson to learn here is, when possible avoid to use global variables.

The Connection is another example of a global variable and this is worst because it is left open after the initial form load. Don't do that. Connectiosn keep valuable system resources locked and thus should be closed immediately after usage applying the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) pattern

```
private void btnConfirmChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string companyName = txtCompanyName.Text;
    string companyAddress = txtCompanyAddress.Text;
    string companyPhone = txtCompanyPhone.Text;

    string Update = @"UPDATE [Club] SET [CompanyName]= @CompanyName,
                      [CompanyAddress]=@CompanyAddress,
                      [CompanyPhone]=@CompanyPhone"; // A where here should be mandatory

    using(OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(aGlobalConnectionStringWouldBeSafeHere))
    using(OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand(Update, dbConn))
    {
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", companyName);
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyAddress", companyAddress);
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyPhone", companyPhone);
        try
        {
           dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           MessageBox.Show("Update Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            return;
        }
   }
}
```

By the way, I hope that your table contains only one record because without a WHERE clause you update every record present with the values of your textboxes.